# $\sum_{j=i}^n\binom nj\binom jix^{n-j}=\binom ni\left(\frac1x+1\right)^{n-i}x^{n-i}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Question :
$$\sum_{j=i}^n\binom nj\binom jix^{n-j}=\binom ni\left(\frac1x+1\right)^{n-i}x^{n-i}$$

I can't prove this identity. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is true, it should be true for each coefficient of $x^k$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^{n-i} x^{n-i} &=\sum_{l=0}^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{l}x^{n-i-l}\\
&=\sum_{j=i}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{j-i}x^{n-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=i}^n \frac{n!}{i! (n-j)! (j-i)!} x^{n-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=i}^n \binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i} x^{n-j}
\end{aligned}
$$
(I leave you the task of filling in the details :))

Answer (score 0):

Re-write the right hand side as

$$\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^{n-i}x^{n-i}=\binom{n}{i}\left(1+x\right)^{n-i}$$

then using the "find the coefficient of $y^i$" operator $\left[y^i\right]$ the above is clearly

$$\left[y^i\right]\left(y+(1+x)\right)^n$$

which may alternatively be written

$$\begin{align}
\left[y^i\right]\left((1+y)+x\right)^n&=\left[y^i\right]\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}\left(1+y\right)^j\\[1ex]
&=\left[y^i\right]\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{j}{i}y^i\\[1ex]
&=\left[y^i\right]\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}x^{n-j}y^i\\[1ex]
&=\left[y^i\right]\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}x^{n-j}y^i\\[1ex]
&=\left[y^i\right]\sum_{i=0}^{n}y^i\left(\sum_{j=i}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}x^{n-j}\right)\\[1ex]
&=\sum_{j=i}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}x^{n-j}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

As your question currently stands, note that proving what you want is equivalent to proving $\displaystyle \sum_{j=i}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}x^{n-j}= \binom{n}{i}(1+x)^{n-i}$

Also note that both the LHS and RHS are polynomials in $x$ of degree $n-i$, so if we want to prove the above $\forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}$, it suffices to prove it $\forall \,  x \in \mathbb{N}$ since two polynomials each of degree $d$ agreeing on at least $d+1$ values, agree everywhere.

Let $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $[x]$ denote the set $\{1,2 \ldots, x\}.$ Here's a combinatorial proof via double-counting.

The RHS counts the number of ways of choosing a core committee of $i$ members out of $n$ people while labeling the $n-i$ non-core committee members with a label from $[x+1].$ This can be done in $\displaystyle \binom{n}{i}(x+1)^{n-i}$  ways.

Alternatively, for a fixed $j, \, i\leq j \leq n,$ from a group of $n$ people, first choose a $j$-member committee in $\displaystyle \binom{n}{j}$ ways and from this committee choose an $i$-member core committee in $\displaystyle \binom{j}{i}$ ways such that the $n-j$ non-committee members get a label from $[x]$ in $x^{n-j}$ ways and the $j-i$ committee members who are $\textbf{not}$ on the core committee get the label $(x+1).$ This can be done in $\displaystyle \binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}x^{n-j}$ ways.

Summing over $j = i, i +1, \ldots, n$, covers all the possible strengths of the intermediate committee from which an $i-$member core committee can be chosen and at each value of $j,$ exactly $n-j+j-i = n-i$ people have a label from $[x+1]$, like in the RHS scenario.

The desired identity follows.

Comment: I am reading your argument now.  Please specify whether $i \geq 0$ or $i \geq 1$.  (I will delete this comment.)

Comment: Why do you say that the $j - i$ committee members who are not on the core committee get the same label?

Comment: It should be $i \geq 0.$ We fix the label of the $j-i$ committee members who are not on the core committee to be $[x+1]$ for 2 reasons: so we can obtain a factor of exactly $x^{n-j}$ in the sum on the LHS and so that the situation corroborates with the one described for the RHS.

Comment: Yes, I agree that $i \geq 0$.  That should have been specified with the identity in the post.